# Difference between std::fstream and Boost Iostreams Library

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am a newbie of BOOST library. Today I saw a small code segment, where reading and writing a PGM format image was implemented with Boost Iostreams Library. As I am more familiar with STL, I can easily tell that std::fstream can do the same job. Then my question is, what's the point of using Boost library in such a simple reading and writing PGM image application? Moreover, I was wondering in which situation BOOST Iostreams Library is most needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `std::fstream` [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/):

> fstream provides an interface to read and write data from files as
>   input/output streams.

From [Boost.Iostreams reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html):

> Boost.Iostreams has three aims:
>
> - To make it easy to create standard C++ streams and stream buffers for accessing new Sources and Sinks.
> - To provide a framework for defining Filters and attaching them to standard streams and stream buffers.
> - To provide a collection of ready-to-use Filters, Sources and Sinks.

Comment: tbh as a semi noob this says nothing to me... what are those filters, sources and sinks that you speak of. When do I need to use them ?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl To know what those filters, source and sinks are, you just have to read the manual of Boost.Iostreams, which I quoted above. Basically, this is how your data bits flow: they come from a source, pass though filters (where you process the data), and arrive to sink(s). You can easily combine source-filters-sinks etc. But if all you need is to read some file into a buffer, as is, you certainly don't need all this.